# C/C++ Eclipse project auto ftp on a unix server in eclipse IDE

Tags: c++, eclipse, unix, synchronization, sftp

I have to write code in C/C++ and upload it to a unix server to run it. I am using eclipse IDE. How can I setup eclipse so that when I click Save the file gets uploaded on the server? I have installed RSE (Remote System Explorer). Now I have the my project locally as well as on the server. I need to synch it.Is there any way to do it?